# Jquery Click and Rotation using add/remove class to set different state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I'm working on a project where I want to expand/collapse content when the user clicks on a chevron (SVG icon), rotating the icon 90 degrees to point down when expanded, and rotating the image back 90 degrees to point right when collapse. The expand functionality works correctly, however I'm having trouble with the collapse. I add/remove classes to create the "expand" vs. "collapse" state. The new class is added correctly, but when I target the new class to collapse, it does nothing. I'm pretty new to jQuery/JS so my code isn't very dynamic or clean, but hoping to get some help here. Thank you all in advance!

```
<div class="result">

<div class="result-header">
    <svg id="expand-result-1" class="svg-icon-24 svg-chevron-expand expand-result-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;}.cls-2{fill:#2a2d30;}</style></defs><title>24</title><g id="empty_icon_margins"><rect class="cls-1 svg-chevron" width="24" height="24"/></g><g id="next"><polygon class="cls-2 svg-chevron" points="11.4 4.7 9.81 6.3 15.01 11.5 9.81 16.7 11.4 18.3 16.6 13.09 18.19 11.5 16.6 9.91 11.4 4.7"/></g></svg>
    <svg class="svg-icon-24 svg-bcite-distinguished svg-bcite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;}.cls-2{fill:#2a2d30;}</style></defs><title>24</title><g id="empty_icon_margins"><rect class="cls-1" width="24" height="24"/></g><g id="bcite_distinguish"><path class="cls-2" d="M18,4H6A2,2,0,0,0,4,6V18a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H18a2,2,0,0,0,2-2V6A2,2,0,0,0,18,4ZM7.93,17.83,6.17,16.07l9.9-9.9,1.77,1.77Z"/></g></svg>
    <a class="result-title" href="" alt="Result Title" title="Result Title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu magna in nisl fermentum tempor.</a>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="result-content result-content-1" id="result-content-1">
    <p>Cras dapibus quis nulla id porttitor. <span class="principle-highlight">Nullam porttitor mollis dui eu egestas. Sed vestibulum risus quam, eget porta dolor iaculis ac. Sed porttitor gravida augue quis pretium. Pellentesque vitae lobortis nunc.</span> Nam nulla erat, viverra vitae nisl eget, facilisis dictum velit. Nam finibus massa eu dui porttitor faucibus. Nullam ullamcorper, libero nec pellentesque fringilla, tellus ex tempus felis, at tincidunt arcu nisi molestie enim.</p>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".result-content" ).hide();
});

$( ".expand-result-1" ).click(function() {
$( "#result-content-1" ).slideDown("slow");
$(this).rotate({
    angle: 0,
    animateTo:90
});
$('#expand-result-1').addClass('collapse-result-1');
$('#expand-result-1').removeClass('expand-result-1');
console.log( "collapse added" );
});

$(".collapse-result-1").click(function() {
console.log( "collapse clicked" );
$( "#result-content-1" ).slideUp("slow");
$(this).rotate({
    angle: 90,
    animateTo:0
});
$('#expand-result-1').removeClass('collapse-result-1');
$('#expand-result-1').addClass('expand-result-1');
});

</script>
```

My thinking behind this is... initiate click function by targeting the class `.expand-result-1`, which works properly, using `slideDown` and a pre-build rotate function (http://jqueryrotate.com/). The rotation animation works properly as well, and the class `expand-result-1` is removed properly, and the class `collapse-result-1` is added properly.

Now, when I go to target `collapse-result-1`, nothing happens. The initial rotation animation works properly, making me think it's still performing the first click function, even though the `expand-result-1` selector class has been remove/replaced.

Again, thank you all in advance for any help you can provide. As I said I'm new to this, and have done considerable searching to find solutions, but nothing that seems to fit my exact scenario.

Comment: You could just add a CSS class and rotate with CSS animation. Would this be okay? I could help with that if needed.

Comment: I'm not opposed to this solution, however I didn't think the rotation part was the culprit, but I'm not experienced enough to know whether or not it's screwing up the collapse function. Worth a try. Thanks!

Comment: @alex.mo.07 do you mind adding the needed CSS to reproduce your example?

Comment: It's because you're not removing the id expand-result-1, so when you click on it, it triggers the 2 click events you defined ;)

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, but neither click function targets the ID so why would that cause it to repeatedly run the initial expand function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that keeps it all in one place (if you're using JQuery anyways) - taking part of Zetura's answer above and combining it with the show/hide state.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.result-content').hide();
});

$('.chevron').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(".result-collapsed")){
        $(this).parent().siblings('.result-content').slideDown("slow");
        $(this).rotate(90);
        $(this).removeClass('result-collapsed');
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().siblings('.result-content').slideUp("slow");
        $(this).rotate(0);
        $(this).addClass('result-collapsed');
    }

});

jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)', 
        '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
        '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)', 
        'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
        '-webkit-transition' : '.3s ease-out',
        '-moz-transition' : '.3s ease-out',
        '-o-transition' : '.3s ease-out'});

    return $(this);
};
```

Edit: Adding HTML for click point

```
<div class="chevron-container result-collapsed"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do it without any JavaScript. But you could keep your JavaScript to show/hide your "result-content" with jQuery slideDown function.

https://jsfiddle.net/Zetura/20qgmenh/

```
.expander {
  display: none;
}

// Rotate SVG chevron
.expander + label svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.expander:checked + label svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

// Show/Hide the content with slide down
.expander + label + .result-content {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expander:checked + label + .result-content {
  max-height: 600px;
}
```